# Can I modify text within Photoshop files programmatically?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

What I want to do is to be able to code a script which will change a text layer from a Photoshop file for another text in my script.

Is there anyway this can be done? Is there any Photoshop API or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's quite a lot you can do with custom scripting. There's a lot to learn and it's got kind of a steep learning curve at first because they have a lot of their own stuff, but it's pretty powerful and flexible.

Adobe's scripts are commonly written in Javascript but can also be written with ActionScript or VB.

Here's a list of resources to get you started:

- [Adobe's Official Documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html)
- [Introduction PDF](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/Adobe_Intro_to_Scripting1.pdf)
- [UI Guide for building dialogs](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui-2-4.pdf) (It is written for inDesign but there's a lot of overlap)

Answer (score 1):

For the folks who arrive here from a search:

```
var newText = "Hello there!";
var textLayer = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName("layer-name");  

textLayer.textItem.contents = newText;
```